# Use case for vertx.clusteredVertx using JavaScript

Tags: vert.x, vertx3

What is the use case for using vertx.clusteredVertx using javascript?

I can start vertx from command line in clustered mode using:

```
vertx run server.js --cluster
```

I can (in my server.js file) create another vertx instance using:

```
var Vertx = require("vertx-js/vertx");
var options = {};
Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, function (res, res_err) {
    if (res_err == null) {
        var vertx = res;
        console.log("We now have a cluster");
    } else {
        console.log("Failed: " + res_err);
    }
});
```

But then vertx gives me a warning:

```
You're already on a Vert.x context, are you sure you want to create a new Vertx instance?
```

So what is the use case for that API (when Vertx is not embedded)?

Answer (score 0):

`--cluster` is useful if you have configured your clustering using external files or other environment settings.

Clustering allows multiple `vertx` instances to share an event bus and other data (in `vertx.sharedData()`). If you do not need this functionality, you do not need clustering.